# How to use JSON-RPC in Struts 2

Tags: java, jquery, json, struts2, json-rpc

I'm using Struts2-json-plugin-2.3.16 with the same version of the framework. I get an empty response from JSON.

The JavaScript/jQuery function.

```
var timeout;
var request;

function getUsers()
{
    if(!request)
    {                    
        request = $.ajax({
            datatype:"json",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "testJsonAction.action",
            success: function(response)
            {
                var user= response.user;
                alert(user);
            },
            complete: function()
            {
                timeout = request = null;
            },
            error: function(request, status, error)
            {
                if(status!=="timeout"&&status!=="abort")
                {
                    alert(status+" : "+error);
                }
            }
        });
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            if(request)
            {
                request.abort();
                alert("The request has been timed out.");
            }
        }, 30000);
    }
}
```

This function is called, when a button is clicked.

```
<s:form namespace="/admin_side" action="Test" validate="true" id="dataForm" name="dataForm">

    <input type="button" name="btnUser" id="btnUser" value="Click" onclick="getUsers();"/>

</s:form>
```

The action class:

```
@Namespace("/admin_side")
@ResultPath("/WEB-INF/content")
@ParentPackage(value = "json-default")
public final class TestAction extends ActionSupport {

    private User user;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TestAction() {
    }

    @JSON(name = "user")
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Action(value = "testJsonAction",
    results = {
        @Result(type = "json", name = ActionSupport.SUCCESS, params = {"enableSMD", "true", "enableGZIP", "true", "excludeNullProperties", "true"})})
    public String executeAction() throws Exception {
        try {
            user = new User();
            user.setName("Tiny");
            user.setDob(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY").parse("29-Feb-2000"));
            user.setLocation("India");
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestAction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Action(value = "Test",
    results = {
        @Result(name = ActionSupport.SUCCESS, location = "Test.jsp"),
        @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Test.jsp")},
    interceptorRefs = {
        @InterceptorRef(value = "defaultStack", params = {"params.acceptParamNames", "", "params.excludeMethods", "load", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"})})
    public String load() throws Exception {
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

The `User` class:

```
public class User
{
    private String name;
    private Date dob;
    private String location;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

The `executeAction()` method in the `TestAction` class is invoked, when the given button is clicked but I do not get a user object as a JSON response. It always seems to be empty.

What is missing here? Does it require other libraries in addition to the the `Struts2-json-plugin-2.3.16` library?

---

Using a direct link like in this case, `http://localhost:8080/TestStruts/admin_side/testJsonAction.action`, I get the following string.

```
{"methods":[],"serviceType":"JSON-RPC","serviceUrl":"\/TestStruts\/admin_side\/testJsonAction.action","version":".1"}
```

Comment: Do you want to use JSON-RPC with the request?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand that. I have seen `JSON-RPC` first time!

Comment: `enableSMD=true` used for [JSON-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) requests. It allows to pass objects to the action to execute methods and return results, so the same object could be used on the client and on the server, everything seems transparent.

Comment: It only worked, when I removed `"root", "stateTables", "enableSMD", "true",` from the list of parameters, `params`. Otherwise, the response was empty. I did not understand.

Comment: `enableSMD` parameter to the json result doesn't serialize root object to the output, instead it returns a JSON-RPC service definition that could be used by the client to call this service methods. But you didn't used `@SMDMethod` annotation on a method that should return an object you can get on the client.

Comment: ... in other words to use JSON-RPC services, which you can define on the server, but seems only version 1.0, current is 2.0. However 2.0 client can handle 1.0 service, depends on implementation.

Comment: ... There're so many implementations, but there's [one](https://plugins.jquery.com/jsonrpcclient/) that registered on jquery site. Also possible to make JSON-RPC requests via `$.ajax`.

Comment: Thank you for these comments. I indeed need to study more about these things. Would you like to answer this question? I do not have a canonical answer. JSON works somehow now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What should you do if you need to use JSON-RPC with Struts2:

Configure action that returns JSON-RPC service

```
@Action(value = "testJsonAction",
  results = @Result(type = "json", params = {"enableSMD", "true"}),
  interceptorRefs = @InterceptorRef(value="json", params={"enableSMD", "true"}))
public String executeAction() throws Exception {
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

create a method

```
@SMDMethod
public User getUser() {

    user = new User();
    user.setName("Tiny");
    user.setLocation("India");

    try {
        user.setDob(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY").parse("29-Feb-2000"));
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestAction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return user;
}
```

Now, you need a JSON-RPC client to make a request, or try `$.ajax`

```
<s:url var="testJsonUrl" action="testJsonAction"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnUser").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "<s:property value='#testJsonUrl'/>",
        dataType:"json",            
        data: JSON.stringify({jsonrpc:'2.0', method:'getUser', id:'jsonrpc'}),  
        contentType: "application/json-rpc; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(response) {
          var user= response.result;  
          alert(JSON.stringify(user));
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried exactly the same thing but the response is always empty. May be, I will have a next question :). It works without `JSON-RPC`.

Comment: Today morning I updated the code with working solution, I didn't check that `ParseException` related to `User` initialization.

Comment: The parse exception is not thrown. I receive this string as a response, `{"methods":[{"name":"getUser","parameters":[]}],"serviceType":"JSON-RPC","serviceUrl":"\/TestStruts\/admin_side\/testJsonAction.action","version":".1"}` with a direct link in the address bar.

Comment: check the `contentType` property, I've changed that, also `serviceUrl` looks strange why it has escaped slash? I have not such escapes. The urls should be equal in the request and service.

Comment: The `getUser()` method annotated with `@SMDMethod` is not invoked. When I add `"root", "user"` to the list of parameters - `param`, the `getUser()` method is invoked but the response is empty then.

Comment: The `contentType` property is the same as mentioned, `contentType: "application/json-rpc; charset=utf-8"`.

Comment: When you pressed the button has `getUser()` invoked? Did you remove `onclick` attribute of the button?

Comment: No it is not invoked, when the button is clicked. It is invoked, when I use a direct link in the address bar like, `http://localhost:8080/TestStruts/admin_side/testJsonAction.action` provided that `"root", "user"` is added to `params` of `@Result`.

Comment: You should not add "root" parameter. Check the javascript is valid and ajax is invoked, also the `json` interceptor does intercept it.

Comment: I do not use the `root` parameter now. This line, `alert(JSON.stringify(user));` inside the `success` handler always alerts `undefined`.

Comment: I have removed the `onclick` attribute of the button. `alert(JSON.stringify(user));` alerts `undefined`.

Comment: Using the `POST` request alerts in the error handler that says, *forbidden* (403).

Comment: what is the jquery version, I used struts2-jquery-plugin 3.6.1 also jqueryui="true" if it make sense.

Comment: No, there is no `struts2-jquery-plugin` on the classpath. I removed it because it did not work throwing some exceptions on application start up. Does it require for `JSON-RPC` to work?

Comment: no, but it setups jquery 10.x.x and it would probably required, I didn't test it on other jquery versions.

Comment: I have downloaded `struts2-jquery-plugin-3.7.0` and added it to the classpath but it did not make a difference. The problem still remains stationary.

Comment: Strange, but do you have a security framework in front of Struts2, also what if you change method POST to GET?

Comment: The `GET` method alerts `undefined` in the `success` handler of jQuery. I use Spring Security but I access those resources after login. Therefore, there should not be security harm. By the way, I have asked a separate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21368194/1391249).

Comment: I have imported `org.apache.struts2.json.annotations.SMDMethod` but in the [documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/json-plugin.html) (at the end), they are using `com.googlecode.jsonplugin.annotations.SMDMethod`. Am I using the right annotation?

Comment: yes, I still think you have a security restrictions, don't know which one without project sources. Try without it, I also forgot to add your namespace to the action url because I used "/" namespace, however I tried with namespace it also works, except parsing date.

Comment: I have tried removing all security constraints still the problem remained unchanged. (commented all XML tags from `spring-security.xml` and security related tags from `web.xml`).

Comment: May be you share a link to some github project, so I can see. However, the first thing I'd done at your place is remove security at all and tried on blank project.