# Using JSON-RPC in Struts2

Tags: jquery, json, struts2, json-rpc, struts2-json-plugin

I use the following JavaScript/jQuery function to make a remote procedure call.

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<s:url var="testJsonUrl" action="testJsonAction"/>

var timeout;
var request;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnUser").click(function(){
        if(!request)
        {
            request = $.ajax({
                datatype:"json",
                type: "GET",
                data: JSON.stringify({jsonrpc:'2.0', method:'getUser', id:'jsonrpc'}),
                contentType: "application/json-rpc; charset=utf-8",
                url: "<s:property value='#testJsonUrl'/>",
                success: function(response)
                {
                    var user = response.result;
                    alert(JSON.stringify(user));  //Always alerts "undefined".
                },
                complete: function()
                {
                    timeout = request = null;
                },
                error: function(request, status, error)
                {
                    if(status!=="timeout"&&status!=="abort")
                    {
                        alert(status+" : "+error);
                    }
                }
            });
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                if(request)
                {
                    request.abort();
                    alert("The request has been timed out.");
                }
            }, 30000);
        }
    });
});
```

The above function is called, when a button is clicked as follows.

```
<s:form namespace="/admin_side" action="Test" validate="true" id="dataForm" name="dataForm">
    <input type="button" name="btnUser" id="btnUser" value="Click"/>
</s:form>
```

The action class in which the method is to be invoked is as follows.

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.InterceptorRef;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Namespace;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.ParentPackage;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.ResultPath;
import org.apache.struts2.json.annotations.SMDMethod;
import util.User;

@Namespace("/admin_side")
@ResultPath("/WEB-INF/content")
@ParentPackage(value = "json-default")
public final class TestAction extends ActionSupport
{
    private User user;

    public TestAction() {}

    @SMDMethod
    public User getUser()
    {
        user = new User();
        user.setName("Tiny");
        user.setLocation("India");

        try {
            user.setDob(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY").parse("29-Feb-2000"));
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestAction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Action(value = "testJsonAction",
    results = {
        @Result(type = "json", params = {"enableSMD", "true", "excludeNullProperties", "true"})},
    interceptorRefs = {
        @InterceptorRef(value = "json", params = {"enableSMD", "true"})})
    public String executeAction() throws Exception {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Action(value = "Test",
    results = {
        @Result(name = ActionSupport.SUCCESS, location = "Test.jsp"),
        @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Test.jsp")},
    interceptorRefs = {
        @InterceptorRef(value = "defaultStack", params = {"params.acceptParamNames", "", "params.excludeMethods", "load", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"})})
    public String load() throws Exception {
        //This method is just needed to return a view on page load.
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

The `User` class:

```
public class User
{
    private String name;
    private Date dob;
    private String location;

    //Setters & getters.
}
```

The `getUser()` method (in the action class `TestAction`) annotated with `@SMDMethod` is expected to be invoked, when the given button is clicked but it does not.

This line `alert(JSON.stringify(user));` in the `success` handler of the jQuery function always alerts `undefined`.

Using a direct link in the address bar like,

```
http://localhost:8080/TestStruts/admin_side/testJsonAction.action
```

returns the following string.

```
{
    "methods": [{
        "name": "getUser",
        "parameters": []
    }],

    "serviceType": "JSON-RPC",
    "serviceUrl": "\/TestStruts\/admin_side\/testJsonAction.action",
    "version": ".1"
}
```

What is missing here? Why does not `JSON-RPC` work?

PS : I'm using `Struts2-json-plugin-2.3.16` with same version of the framework.

Comment: Do you have a folder name admin_side?

Comment: Yes there is a folder `admin_side` where JSP pages are placed. Its location is `WEB-INF/content/admin_side`.

Comment: Could you change namespace of the action to "/"?

Comment: Or better idea is change the name of the method to something else "doSomething".

Comment: The method was renamed to `doSomething()` and the URL was changed to `<s:url var="testJsonUrl" action="/testJsonAction"/>` that made no difference.

Comment: @RomanC : I'm still unable to solve the issue. Which jQuery library do you use for jQuery functions to work? I use `jquery-1.8.0.min.js`.

Comment: I tested it with this version also, but loading from google.

Comment: Once again, I have tried removing security and It worked but only with the `POST` method. Is it mandatory to have only the `POST` request while using `JSON-RPC`? Also `includeProperties` has no effect. When I try, `"includeProperties", "user\\[\\d+\\]\\.name, user\\[\\d+\\]\\.location"`, all the properties namely `name`, `dob` and `location` from the `User` class are received in the response (the field `dob` in this case, should have been excluded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it mandatory to have only the POST request while using JSON-RPC?

yes, it only works with POST request

> Also `includeProperties` has no effect

`includeProperties` has effect if it's a parameter to `json` interceptor. Don't confuse the name of parameter used with `json` result.

> the field `dob` in this case, should have been excluded

In this case better to use `excludeProperties` parameter to interceptor, like this

```
@Action(value = "testJsonAction",
results = {
    @Result(type = "json", params = {"enableSMD", "true"})},
interceptorRefs = {
    @InterceptorRef(value = "json", params = {"enableSMD", "true", "excludeProperties", "result\\.dob"})})
public String executeAction() throws Exception {
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This worked indeed. I incorrectly assumed that the parameters of `includeProperties` were to  be set to `user`. I however, had to use this regx (as you mentioned in one of the answers), `"result\\[\\d+\\]\\.stateId, result\\[\\d+\\]\\.stateName"` while retrieving a list of states from the database. Simply escaping a dot `.` like `"result\\.stateId, result\\.stateName"` resulted in fetching an empty list in the response. I have now a new issue still remaining which is about Spring Security!!! Sorry, I have given you a lot trouble!

Comment: Can we have a parameterized `@SMDMethod` method? Referring to the example in the question, can we pass parameters to the `getUser()` method? This [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/JSON+Plugin) (the last section, JSON-RPC) shows examples but it uses the dojo plugin.

Comment: The `result` is a root object is being serialized, and it's the object that the method returns. In this example it's a `User` bean, so the regex will be just dot reference to a property. If the return object is List then it will be like you wrote, didn't test it. Parameters should be passed with `parameters:[]` and there's `@SMDMethodParameter`.

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify({jsonrpc:'2.0', method:'getUser', id:'jsonrpc', parameters:[{'userId':1}]})` and in the action class, `public User getUser(@SMDMethodParameter(name="userId")Long userId){...}` says, `SEVERE: Method getUser could not be found in action class.` I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: is this a valid json?

Comment: JSON works, when this parameter `userId` is not used anymore i.e it works with `data: JSON.stringify({jsonrpc:'2.0', method:'getUser', id:'jsonrpc'})` and there is a parameterless method in the action class like `public User getUser(){...}`.

Comment: Ok, use parameters as array of object values: `params:[1]` for example.